# Rust Pattern to Hold Reference to Builder in Struct

Tags: rust

I'm fairly new to Rust, and I am trying to use a library which wraps the SDL2 C library. Apologies for the abstract question, but I'm hoping this is a very common pattern with a solution that the Rust community can point me towards. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
pub struct Gfx {
    texture_creator: TextureCreator<WindowContext>,
}

pub struct Sprite<'a> {
    texture: Texture<'a>,
}

impl Gfx {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        // do things to initialize a texture_creator
        Self {
            texture_creator
        }
    }
    pub fn build_sprite(&self) -> Sprite {
        let some_filepath = Path::new("/foo/bar/baz");
        let tmp = Surface::from_file(some_filepath).unwrap();
        let texture = self.texture_creator.create_texture_from_surface(tmp).unwrap();

        Sprite {
            texture: texture
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I want to use this in my code, the compiler will see something like:

```
let gfx = Gfx::new();
let my_sprite = gfx.build_sprite();

gfx.render() // or whatever else I want to do with gfx, which may be mutable...
```

And the compiler will complain that I've borrowed mutably after borrowing immutably.

I understand the problem the compiler is trying to prevent, namely since a reference to `TextureCreator` is held by `my_sprite`, it cannot guarantee that the reference to `TextureCreator` will not change after I begin using `my_sprite`. However, I don't really understand how to think about the problem from a Rust perspective to avoid this issue.

How can I have a structure which holds a reference to something which creates children referencing itself? Is there a way I can tell the compiler, "I promise that all my sprites will live at least as long as the `texture_creator` and that I promise when I borrow this structure to `build_sprite`, I will never alter anything?"

Comment: Generally, builders take ownership of the old item by using `self` as an argument, as opposed to `&self`. Which crate are you using?

Comment: Why does `Texture` have a lifetime parameter?

Comment: @JeremyMeadows I am using https://crates.io/crates/sdl2. I need &self since, afaik, I cannot clone or otherwise reference the `texture_creator`, and in that case it will complain that the data is owned locally by the builder function.

Comment: @PitaJ The lifetime isn't actually my issue (at least I don't think it is). The lifetime exists because the crate designed a texture in such a way as to hold a lifetime reference: https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/render/struct.Texture.html  

I believe it's introduced to ensure it lives as long as the `TextureCreator`

Comment: I don't think there's a solution to this. The compiler sees that you hold a reference to the struct, so can not allow you to mutate it. I assume `render()` operates on some other fields in your struct? You could wrap those in a `RefCell` to allow mutability through an immutable reference (checking at runtime instead).

Comment: Otherwise you'll have to use unsafe.

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks. Yeah, that's currently what I'm doing (i.e. using `RefCell`), but I was wondering if there was maybe a more elegant "rust-y" way of doing things. Thanks :)